# Passing function pointers with generic arguments in D

Tags: casting, function-pointers, d, void-pointers

I'm trying to create an implementation of an "each" method for arrays. I want to be able to use it like this:

```
void each(void*[] arr, void function(void*) f) {
    assert(arr != null);
    foreach(int i, void* x ; arr){
        f(&x);
    }
} 
void setToFive(int* x){
    *x = 5
}

int main(){
    int[] arr = new int[50];
    each(arr, &setToFive);
    writeln(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

But, I get the error: 
`function test.each (void*[] stuff, void function(void*) f) is not callable using argument types (int[], void function(int* x))`

Am I going about this problem in the wrong way, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int[] cannot be cast to an array of void*. I recommend using templates.

```
void each(Type)(Type[] array, void delegate(ref Type) cb){
    foreach(ref element; array)
        cb(element);
}

void main(){
    int[] arr = new int[50];
    arr.each((e){ e += 5; });
}
```

I currently can't check if this compiles properly, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Using DMD, I needed a slight modification: `arr.each((ref int e) {e += 5})`. It seems the compiler won't assume that e is a ref without it being explicitly specified.